# Check if word exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have this to check if word exists in string, but oddly its not working, anyone know why?

```
        print("->",x)
        print("e.widget.get: ",e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

        if x in e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c"):
            print("exist")
        else:
            print("not")
```

this prints:

> ->  idTag
> e.widget.get:  idTag
> not

it should print exist instead of not, why is this?

Comment: Are you sure `e.widget.get` is returning a string?

Comment: yes, i had to remove the spaces in the x... :/ now need to remove the case sensitive because it accepts idTag but not idtag

Comment: fix with if x.replace(" ","").upper() in e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c").upper():

Answer (score 1):

it was a mather of spaces....

```
 for x in thislist:
    print("start")
    print("->",x)
    print("e.widget.get ",e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
    if x.replace(" ","") in e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c"):
        print("exist")
    else:
        print("not")
```